# Detecting the full load the flex dashboard page

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'm using a rather complex flexdashboard structure with 10 pages and several graphics. The loading time is about 30" and I would like to show on each page the text "Loading data..." until the charts are effectively available.

To reach this, I've inserted in each page a Loading data... and I'm using a Javascript to detect when the page is loaded to set the visibility to hidden for all the .

When the charts are loaded, the text "Loading data..." does not hide.

Here is a reproducible example:

````
---
title: 'Reprex'
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: column
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
tags$head(tags$script(src = "script.js"))

```

Reprex{data-icon="fa-chart-bar"}
===================================== 

<div id="loading">Loading data...</div>


```{r}
renderPlot({
  
  Sys.sleep(5) #it's just to mimic the elaboration time
  plot(cars)
  
  })

```
````

Here is the content of the javascript file (that sits in the same directory of the RMD file:

```
$(document).on('shiny:busy', function(event) {
  var cont = document.getElementById("loading");
  cont.style.visibility = "visible";
});

$(document).on('shiny:idle', function(event) {
  var cont = document.getElementById("loading");
  cont.style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

Thank you in advance for your kind support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

````
---
title: 'Reprex'
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: column
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny

---

```{js}
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("loading-done", function(data){
    document.querySelector(`[data-loading="${data.loading_id}"]`).style.display = "none"
})
```

Reprex{data-icon="fa-chart-bar"}
===================================== 

<div data-loading="loading-1">Loading data...</div>


```{r}
renderPlot({
    Sys.sleep(5) #it's just to mimic the elaboration time
    on.exit(session$sendCustomMessage("loading-done", list(loading_id = "loading-1")))
    plot(cars)
})

```
````

1. Change `id` to custom `data-loading` property, because `flexdashboard` adds some prefix to your IDs. Don't want to waste time predicting the pattern.
2. Make a `<div data-loading="loading-1"> ... </div>` on each of your page, just remember to change the loading ID. `data-loading="loading-X"` is paired with `list(loading_id = "loading-x")` on server.
3. When the plot finishes, sends a signal to JS to hide the message.

##### Alternation

I would suggest you use other loader libraries so you don't need to write your own JS.

````
---
title: 'Reprex'
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: column
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny

---

```{r include=FALSE}
library(spsComps)
```

Reprex{data-icon="fa-chart-bar"}
===================================== 

```{r}
plotOutput("plot1")
```

```{r}
loader1 <- addLoader$new(
    target_selector = "plot1",
    footer = h4("Loading data...")
)

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    loader1$show()
    Sys.sleep(5) #it's just to mimic the elaboration time
    on.exit(loader1$hide())
    plot(cars)
})
```
````

[image]

For this, each page needs its own loader.

If you want multiple pages, we can use the `full_screen` loader so all pages can share the same loader.

````
---
title: 'Reprex'
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: column
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny

---

```{r include=FALSE}
library(spsComps)
```

Reprex{data-icon="fa-chart-bar"}
===================================== 

```{r}
plotOutput("plot1")
```

```{r}
loader1 <- addLoader$new(
    target_selector = "body", isID = FALSE, method = "full_screen",
    footer = h4("Loading data..."), height = "300px"
)

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    loader1$show()
    Sys.sleep(2) #it's just to mimic the elaboration time
    on.exit(loader1$hide())
    plot(cars)
})
```


Reprex{data-icon="fa-home"}
=====================================

```{r}
renderUI({
    loader1$show()
    Sys.sleep(2)
    on.exit(loader1$hide())
    div("another page")
})

```
````

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you for providing the missing code in a clear and detailed manner :-)
The "on.exit" trigger the desire behaviour and my remaining issue is to get the on.exit procedure triggered when the full code has been elaborated. It looks like that the on.exit statement is executed when there is still some processing running in the background. Any idea of the statement to be used to trap the end of those background processes?

Comment: PS: I'm using the first method as I find it easier to integrate in my app.

Comment: @XavierBronlet Can't reproduce what you said "on.exit statement is executed when there is still some processing running in the background". Any example?

Comment: sure. I've published the App with the code from initial suggestion. I just inserted an animated gif instead of the text. You will find it here https://acclab.shinyapps.io/SA_Flex_Shiny_mod
You will see the spinner disappearing but no content is loaded and you will have to wait for some more seconds. NLP page appears to be the one that take the most to be loaded.

Comment: The spinner gif never disappears on the NLP tab. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Ooups... there is an issue with the NLP analysis, I published the App without the NLP page to illustrate the issue. Additional info: the issue appears when running the the document in R Studio, with Safari and with Chrome. With Firefox on MacOS, it works properly... Any idea about what I should change?

Comment: Then, this could be a browser rendering difference. There may be some delay when the browser switches from one job to another. So the job is done, but some browsers take longer to display it. It is hard to find one solution for all. As long as there is only a few seconds delay, I think that's acceptable.

Comment: Right, thank you for your valuable help :-)